# Can't mock module function used in my react action thunk jest

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm currently trying to test my thunk action (getUserFeatureNames) to see if it calls a success action(getUserFeatureNamesSuccess) using jest. getUserFeatureNames thunk action currently resides in loginActions.js file which is import homeQueries(which i'm trying to mock). So far I'm getting the following error when running my jest test..

TypeError: _homeQueries2.default.getFeatureNames is not a function

How do i mock homeQueries.getFeatureNames?

```
function createStore(state = {}, expectActions = {}){
  const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
  return mockStore(state, expectActions);
}

describe("home_async_tests", () => {

test("getUserFeatureNamesSuccess action is called if request was success", (done) => {

jest.mock('../../../graphQL/homeQueries', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
     {
      getFeatureNames: () =>{
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let array = [{iconFile: 'Personalization.png', description: 'Personalization'},{iconFile: 'Home.png', description: 'Home'}];
            resolve(array);
          });
      };
    }
  });

});
jest.dontMock('../../../app/redux/actions/homeActions');
let homeActions = require('../../../app/redux/actions/homeActions');
const expectedAction = {type: types.userFeatureNamesSuccess, payLoad: {isError: false, data: '' }};
const store = createStore();
store.dispatch(homeActions.getUserFeatureNames({token:"fdis4554" })).then(() => {
  const actions = store.getActions();
  expect(actions[0].type).toEqual(expectedAction.type);
  expect(actions[0].payLoad.isError).toEqual(expectedAction.payLoad.isError);
  done();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the module just return an object and not a function that returns an object, so your mock should look like this:

```
jest.mock('../../../graphQL/homeQueries', () = > ({
    getFeatureNames: () = > {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) = > {
        let array = [{
          iconFile: 'Personalization.png',
          description: 'Personalization'
        }, {
          iconFile: 'Home.png',
          description: 'Home'
        }];
        resolve(array);
      });
    };
  }
});
```